# Is object global null or not?

Tags: c#, java, asp.net, .net

I have a code which is shown below. I was asked in an interview

```
object global;
void f()
{
  object local=new object();
  global=local;
}
```

He asked, "Is global `null` outside the function?". Since the `local` variable loses its scope outside the function and its reference is given to `global` it should also be `null` but it isn't why?

Comment: Unless you call `f()`, `global` will stay null.

Comment: If the function is run, global will get the value of local, and keep it even after function ended. If not, global is null

Comment: Yeah the function is called why global is not null

Comment: Even if it were C++, interviewer wouldn't have a point, because new operator create object not on stack, but in heap.

Comment: @Harm: What I thought, but I'll rather not claim I know anything about C++ ;p

Comment: @Prabhavith because in function there is `global=local`, so global will get the value of local

Comment: Is local garbage collected or not or both local and global exists out side the function

Comment: Garbage collection works on memory blocks, not on variables.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to differentiate between variables and values.

The local variable only exists inside the function, but that doesn't mean that the value that the variable contains doesn't exist outside the function.

When you assign the value of `local` to `global`, you are copying the reference to the object so that there are two reference to the same object. The local variable goes away when you leave the function, but the value that you copied to the global variable still exists, and the object survives as there is still a reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

I did a plenty of research regarding this question and found that the sole reason of this behavior is due to .Net Garbage Collection.

> GC roots are not objects in themselves but are instead references to objects. Any object referenced by a GC root will automatically survive the next garbage collection.

Since local is a local variable it will stay in GC root and, since it is referenced by global it survives the GC.
You can get more information in

http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/understanding-garbage-collection-in-.net/